# How to Extract Data from Tags Using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to retrieve data from a website.  My code is as follows:

```
import re
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# gets a file-like object using urllib2.urlopen
url = 'http://ecal.forexpros.com/e_cal.php?duration=weekly'
html = urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# loops over all <tr> elements with class 'ec_bg1_tr' or 'ec_bg2_tr'
for tr in soup.find_all('tr', {'class': re.compile('ec_bg[12]_tr')}):
    # finds desired data by looking up <td> elements with class names

    event = tr.find('td', {'class': 'ec_td_event'}).text
    currency = tr.find('td', {'class': 'ec_td_currency'}).text
    actual = tr.find('td', {'class': 'ec_td_actual'}).text
    forecast = tr.find('td', {'class': 'ec_td_forecast'}).text
    previous = tr.find('td', {'class': 'ec_td_previous'}).text
    time = tr.find('td', {'class': 'ec_td_time'}).text
    importance = tr.find('td', {'class': 'ec_td_importance'}).img.get('alt')

    # the returned strings are unicode, so to print them we need to use a unicode string
    if importance == 'High':
        print(u'\t{:5}\t{}\t{:3}\t{:40}\t{:8}\t{:8}\t{:8}'.format(time, importance, currency, event, actual, forecast, previous))
```

The first few records in the result set are as follows:

```
05:00   High    EUR CPI (YoY)                                   1.3%        1.3%        1.3%    
10:00   High    USD Pending Home Sales (MoM)                    1.5%        0.7%        -0.7%   
21:45   High    CNY Caixin Manufacturing PMI                    51.1        50.4        50.4    
00:30   High    AUD RBA Interest Rate Decision                  1.50%       1.50%       1.50%   
00:30   High    AUD RBA Rate Statement                                                          
03:55   High    EUR German Manufacturing PMI                    58.1        58.3        58.3    
03:55   High    EUR German Unemployment Change                  -9K         -5K         6K
```

I'm trying to now retrieve similar data from the following website:

https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar

To do so, I revised the above-mentioned code as follows:

```
import re
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# gets a file-like object using urllib2.urlopen
url = 'https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar'
html = urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)


for tr in soup.find_all('tr', {'class': re.compile('fxst-tr-event fxst-oddRow  fxit-eventrow fxst-evenRow ')}):
    # finds desired data by looking up <div> elements with class names

    event = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-eventInfo-time fxs_event_time'}).text
    currency = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-event-name'}).text
    actual = tr.find('div', {'class': ' fxit-actual'}).text
    forecast = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-consensus'}).text
    previous = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxst-td-previous fxit-previous'}).text
    time = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-eventInfo-time fxs_event_time'}).text
#    importance = tr.find('td', {'class': 'ec_td_importance'}).img.get('alt')

    # the returned strings are unicode, so to print them we need to use a unicode string
    if importance == 'High':
        print(u'\t{:5}\t{:3}\t{:40}\t{:8}\t{:8}\t{:8}'.format(time, currency, event, actual, forecast, previous))
```

This code does not return any results (presumably because I'm referencing incorrect tags and/or classes).  Does anyone see where my error is?

Thanks!

Comment: I looked through the website, there is no _class_ named `fxst-tr-event fxst-oddRow  fxit-eventrow fxst-evenRow `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **[`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)** + [**`Chromedriver`**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)/[`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) to parse through dynamically created JavaScript content, `urllib2` doesn't handle that. I don't think it does much sense to use `regex` here, you can use the `lxml` parser to allow multiple classes and use them in a list. Below is an example using the already mentioned tools:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for tr in soup.findAll('tr',{'class':['fxst-tr-event', 'fxst-oddRow', 'fxit-eventrow', 'fxst-evenRow', 'fxs_cal_nextEvent']}):
    event = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-eventInfo-time fxs_event_time'}).text
    currency = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-event-name'}).text
    actual = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-actual'}).text
    forecast = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-consensus'}).text
    previous = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxst-td-previous fxit-previous'}).text
    time = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-eventInfo-time fxs_event_time'}).text

    print(time, currency, event, actual, forecast, previous)
```

---

Note `lxml` is a library itself, you can handle multiple classes using the standard `html.parser` but it's not as intuitive in my opinion. This code prints:

```
14:00 
CAD                                     14:00 None 59.2 
61.6                                    
14:00 
CAD                                     14:00 52.9  
63.9                                    
17:00 
USD                                     17:00 765 
...
...
```

I haven't altered any of the variables because I'm not really sure what you want them to be, so further adjusting of that and formatting the output should be ideal.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm attempting to modify your code to include the 'expected volatility' by inserting 'volatility = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-eventInfo-vol-c fxit-event-info-desktop'}).text' as the last variable in the for loop.  It doesn't seem to work.  Any idea why?

Comment: It works for me, a bunch of 1s and 2s. What would be the expected output?

Comment: The expected output is:  1 = "low volatility expected", 2 = "moderate volatility expected" and 3 = "high volatility expected

Comment: I'm seeing 1s, 2s, and 3s... Just curious how to extract the "low", "medium" and "high"?

Comment: I'm glad to help! Please remember to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)/upvote the answer if it was helpful, it's an overall good for the community. For your last question. it's into `span` tag named `title`, you just need to find the `span` tag inside using `.find` and then ask for the `['title']`.

Comment: @equanimity Something like: `volatility = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-eventInfo-vol-c fxit-event-info-desktop'}).span['title']` will then store this value: `'Low volatility expected'`